# How to make an arithmetic program that would print "invalid" if there's like double sign or invalid operation

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an arithmetic program that would print `invalid` if there's like a double sign or invalid operation like (`++`, `--`, `+*`, etc) so I'm trying to write the if `elif` possibility one by one.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the pict of the program that I just mentioned doing. So I was thinking if it's possible to write all of that in one `elif` and I try to write `elif` (`+-`, `-+`, `++`, `//`). I also tried `elif` (`+/` or `/+`) but none of them are works

Comment: Please don't post [code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Don't check for every possible error, and instead just check if it's one of the (smaller number of) correct operations or not.

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need so many if-elif statements

```
ops=input('Options: ')
if ops not in['+', '-', '/', '*']:
    print('Invalid Operation')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the conditions in one expression in an if statemant by using `or` as follows:

```
ops = input('User Input: ')
if ops == '++' or ops == '--' or ops == '+/':  # add all invalid inputs here
    print(f'invalid {ops}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
invalid_operators = ['++', '+=', '-+', '+*', '+/', '--', '-/', '**', '/*', '//', '-/']

input_int = input("Enter arithmetic operation ")
for i, ele in enumerate(input_int):
  if i < len(input_int)-1:
    if str(input_int[i]) + str(input_int[i+1]) in invalid_operators: #Checking validity
      print("Invalid ")
  else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep your same use case (Giving the whole operation as an input and checking if the operator is contained in the given string), you can define a collection of invalid operators and use the any() function:

```
invalid_operators = ['//', '++', '/*']
if any(invalid_op in ops for invalid_op in invalid_operators):
    print("Invalid operator!")
```